# Automatically run command on each node on startup with cssh?

Tags: cluster-ssh

I have a cluster configured in my .csshrc config file, with several nodes. I want that when I open this cluster, a given command is run on each node automatically. The command is different for each node. Actually, the commands are very similar for each node, only a few characters change from node to node.
Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: Did you look at [pssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh) ?